# Minimum element in diagonal strips of square matrix?

Tags: c, matrix, diagonal

I need to find the minimum in each diagonal strip (perpendicular to main diagonal) for square matrix. The code I'm using, does in fact output each strip, but for some reason it doesn't find the min element.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int min[10], x[3][3] = { 1, 2, 3,
                             4, 5, 6,
                             7, 8, 9};
    int n = 3, d, j, z, i, k;

    for (d = 0, i = 0; d < 2 * n - 1; d++, i++){
        printf("D %d: ", d);
        z = (d < n) ? 0 : d - n + 1;
        for (j = z; j <= d - z; j++){
            printf("%d ", x[j][d - j]);
            if(d == 0 || d == 2 * n - 2){
                min[i] = x[j][d - j];
                break;
            }
            min[i] = x[j][d - j];
            for (k = j + 1; k <= d - z; k++){
                if (min[i] > x[k][d - k])
                    min[i] = x[k][d - k];
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++)
        printf("min = %d\n", min[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
D 0: 1
D 1: 2 4
D 2: 3 5 7
D 3: 6 8
D 4: 9
min = 1
min = 4
min = 7
min = 8
min = 9
```

But in this case it should be

```
min = 1
min = 2
min = 3
min = 6
min = 9
```

Comment: This is probably a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For example, using a debugger you could step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. That makes it easy to see if any calculation or expression is incorrect.

Comment: Care to provide an illustrative example?

Comment: I've update with an output if that helps.

Comment: AFAICS, `d == i` at all times in the main loop (not the printing loop), so you don't need both variables in the main loop.  However, that's tangential to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make it more complicated than needed and I find it hard to understand what your algorithm is.

I'll suggest that you simply calculates the minimum in the loop where you do the printing.

Something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int min[10], x[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3},
                             {4, 5, 6},
                             {7, 8, 9}};
    int n = 3, d, j, z, i;

    for (d = 0, i = 0; d < 2 * n - 1; d++, i++){
        printf("D %d: ", d);
        z = (d < n) ? 0 : d - n + 1;
        for (j = z; j <= d - z; j++){
            printf("%d ", x[j][d - j]);
            if (j == z)
            {
              // First time for this strip
              // So just initialize min to current element
              min[d] = x[j][d - j];
            }
            else if (min[d] > x[j][d - j])
            {
              // Current element is less than min
              // So overwrite min with current element
              min[d] = x[j][d - j];
            }
            if(d == 0 || d == 2 * n - 2){
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++)
        printf("min = %d\n", min[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can control the loops with fewer special conditions.  The main trouble in the original loop was that you had triple nested loops where double nested loops are sufficient.  This meant you kept on setting the `min` to a new value too often.

This code prints out the subscripts of the elements of the array as well as the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int min[10], x[3][3] =
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, },
        { 4, 5, 6, },
        { 7, 8, 9, },
    };
    int n = 3;

    for (int d = 0; d < 2 * n - 1; d++)
    {
        printf("D %d: ", d);
        int z = (d < n) ? 0 : d - n + 1;
        printf("A[%d][%d] = %d: ", z, d - z, x[z][d - z]);
        min[d] = x[z][d - z];
        for (int j = z + 1; j <= d - z; j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d][%d] = %d: ", j, d - j, x[j][d - j]);
            if (x[j][d-j] < min[d])
                min[d] = x[j][d-j];
        }
        printf("min[%d] = %d\n", d, min[d]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++)
        printf("min = %d\n", min[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
D 0: A[0][0] = 1: min[0] = 1
D 1: A[0][1] = 2: A[1][0] = 4: min[1] = 2
D 2: A[0][2] = 3: A[1][1] = 5: A[2][0] = 7: min[2] = 3
D 3: A[1][2] = 6: A[2][1] = 8: min[3] = 6
D 4: A[2][2] = 9: min[4] = 9

min = 1
min = 2
min = 3
min = 6
min = 9
```